# Combine multiple csv files in one excel table

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have the following problem:

I have a lot of csv files, in each csv file there two columns that are used for lookups and depending the value in those columns, I want to extract some values from this csv into an excel sheet that is meant to combine all the CSV files.

In the excel sheet one row belongs to a csv and the columns are the values that I extract from each csv file.

an example csv would look like this:

```
id1;id2;values;
0;0;a
0;0;b
0;0;c
0;1;a
0;1;b
0;1;c
1;0;a
1;0;b
...
```

ABC being a set of values that belong to a certain ID1/ID2 combination.
and the final excel sheet should look like that

```
csv;val00A;val00B;val00C;val01A;val01B;val01C;val10A...
nameOfCsv;0.1;0.2;0.12;...
```

So basically I want to look up the values ABC for a certain ID1 and ID2 that take up a few rows in those csv files and paste them in a single row per csv setup.

I know that this should be possible with some indexing and lookups but I'm a scrub at excel thus am asking you.
If someone has any idea, please enlighten me

Comment: This would be easy to do if you pulled the CSV files into Access first. Create a query to get the values you want and then crosstab it. Send the results back out to Excel.

Comment: where did you get the second part `nameOfCsv;0,1;0,2;0,12;...` of the expected result from? why some values are separated by semicolon while some by comma?

Comment: @TerryW my bad, those commas are supposed to be dots, those are float values. the first line would be the variables and the second and so on the stuff I want to fill from the csv